# Quotes/Double Quotes within PHP/MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is the piece of code I am currently working with:

```
$outputDisplay .= '<div class="col-md-3">
                      <p class="launch">Mission: '.$mission.'</p>';

//If there are mission details, they will be displayed here
if (!$details){
    $outputDisplay .= "";
}
else{
    $outputDisplay .= '<a href="'.$details.'"target="_blank">Mission Details</a>';
}
//Closes out mission/details section
$outputDisplay .= '</div>';
```

I am building a row and here is what I am trying to accomplish. It will display data from `$mission` regardless, there will always be information there. However, there are not always websites that are associated with missions, represented by `$details`. `$details` is a website address or nothing at all.

In short, if there is information there, I want it to be represented as a link. I think I am getting backwards with the various quotes and double quotes. Any help would be great for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 5):

Just use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc), which eliminates having to worry about quotes at the PHP level:

```
if ($details) {
    $outputDisplay .= <<<EOL
<a href="{$outputDisplay}" target="_blank">Mission Details</a>
EOL;
}
```

Comment: No dice, page still displays blank.

Comment: so figure out why `$details` is evaluating to boolean false. or do you mean the ENTIRE page is blank? IN that case, you've got a "whitescreen of death" and there's plenty of dupes on how to figure that out.

Comment: White screen of death I am afraid

Comment: Parse error, syntax unexpected end of file, last line. Hmm, less than helpful, isn't it? :)

Comment: then you're missing something on an earlier line, e.g. a `}` or whatever.

Comment: FOUND IT. Thanks for your patience. :)